# Match the substring in a string and append the substring with #tags

Tags: apex, string, regular-expressions

I have a string in that match the substring and append the substring with #tag like #Test#;

```
String str = 'This is a TesT for reteSt the tEsTing which will confirm that test was not TEsTed perfectly by teSTer';

String str2 = 'test';

return 'This is a #TesT# for re#teSt# the #tEsT#ing which will confirm that #test# was not #TEsT#ed perfectly by #teST#er';
```

i have tried in many ways iam unable to achieve output;
please help

```
String myString1 = 'This is a TesT for reteSt the tEsTing which will confirm that test was not TEsTed perfectly by teSTer';

String myString2 = 'test';

string replacement='#test#';

string result = myString1.replaceAll('(?i)'+myString2,replacement);
system.debug(result);
```

iam getting result but it is case insensitive.

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is much easier and less code to implement by means of regex.

You did a good attempt. A couple of minor changes are required.

Take a look at the working online example https://regex101.com/r/FBhTZp/1 it also contains an explanation to it.

`(?i)(test)` - any part of the expression to the right of `(?i)` is a case insensitive.

`#$0#` - `$0`  matches the found group. In this regex, we have only one group.

```
String input = 'This is a TesT for reteSt the tEsTing which will confirm that test was not TEsTed perfectly by teSTer';
String regexToFind = '(?i)(test)';
String regexToReplace = '#$0#';

String output = input.replaceAll(regexToFind, regexToReplace);
System.debug('output: ' + output);
```

result is:

> DEBUG|output: This is a #TesT# for re#teSt# the #tEsT#ing which will
> confirm that #test# was not #TEsT#ed perfectly by #teST#er

---